# while loop exiting instead of looping when criteria not met

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop

i'm writing a function as part of a larger overall class project, and i'm having multiple issues with this looping statement, could any of you tell me how it's not looping even though its not meeting the exit criteria? i get what i need up until the loop, i'm trying to get it to ask you to select an item to add, print out the print statement, then start over and if you select the same item twice, add it to the cart

```
print("**********ITEMS**********")
print("1................Shirts - $10")
print("2.................Pants - $20")
print("3.................Shoes - $40")
print("4.................Dress - $50")
print("Complete Purchase")
cart = []
items = 0
def addItems():
    items = int(input("please add an item to your cart: "))
    while items > 0:
        if items == 1:
            print("Shirts,{}x,${}".format(+1, +10))
            cart.count("Shirt")
            cart.append("Shirt")
            print(cart)
            return cart
        elif items == 2:
            print("Pants,{}x,${}".format(+1, +20))
            #cart.count("Pants")
            cart.append("Pants")
            return cart
        elif items == 3:
            print("Shoes,{}x,${}".format(+1, +40))
            #cart.append("Shoes")
            cart.count("Shoes")
            return cart
        elif items == 4:
            print("Dress,{}x,${}".format(+1, +50))
            #cart.append("Dress")
            cart.count("Dress")
            return cart
        elif items > 5:
            break
        #return cart
   # print(cart.count("Shirt") * 10 + cart.count("Pants") * 20 + cart.count("Shoes") * 40 + cart.count("Dress") * 50)


addItems()
```

this is my output below

```
please add an item to your cart: 1
Shirts,1x,$10
['Shirt']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What do you think `return` does?

Comment: A `while` loop repeats when the criteria is met, so it's supposed to exit when the criteria is not met.

Comment: The criteria is the looping criteria, not the exit criteria.

Comment: `cart.count("Shirt")` doesn't do anything. It returns the count, but you never do anything with that result.

Comment: You say you want to add the item to the cart only if you select the same item twice. Your code always adds the item to the cart. And if you don't add to the cart the first time, how will you know that they selected the same item again, since the only memory is in the cart?

Comment: Anyway, the fix to your main problem is to just get rid of all the `return cart` lines.

Comment: i was under the impression that return changes the global variable, because its local while in the function

Answer (score 0):

You should remove 'return cart' from your if-elif ladder and add it to outside of the while loop. Also you could take input from the user in while loop in addition to the previous one, at the end of the while loop.

```
def addItems():
    items = int(input("please add an item to your cart: "))
    while items > 0:
        if items == 1:
            print("Shirts,{}x,${}".format(+1, +10))
            cart.count("Shirt")
            cart.append("Shirt")
            print(cart)
        elif items == 2:
            print("Pants,{}x,${}".format(+1, +20))
            #cart.count("Pants")
            cart.append("Pants")
        elif items == 3:
            print("Shoes,{}x,${}".format(+1, +40))
            #cart.append("Shoes")
            cart.count("Shoes")
        elif items == 4:
            print("Dress,{}x,${}".format(+1, +50))
            #cart.append("Dress")
            cart.count("Dress")
        elif items > 5:
            break
        items = int(input("please add an item to your cart: "))
    return cart
```